# Write a MaskedTextbox validation for a phone number VB.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, textbox

How do you write a MaskedTextbox validation for a phone number which has to contain 10 Numbers.

eng. (999) 000-0000

If the phone number does not contain 10 numbers. The program will prompt the user to enter a correct phone number.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I think it will help.

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/666932/Using-Masked-TextBox-in-NET

There is a `MaskedTextBox` control that you can utilize. It's the same as a regular text box except for you need to set the `Mask` property.

You might look at a mask such as `"(000) 000-0000"` .

Comment: @learningtocode scroll to the bottom of that link and look at the code.

Comment: Thanks ill take a look at it. @feltersnach

Comment: I'm coming here from a low quality review. Please try to include code samples as a part of your answer and avoid link-only answers. Links can go dead over time.